# Create LocationRequest for API lower than 31

Tags: android, android-location, android-fusedlocation

I have compileSdkVersion 32 and now I can create `LocationRequest` only using `LocationRequest.Builder`. LocationRequest.create() currently unavailable, means I can't even call this deprecated static method. So any suggestions how to create LocationRequest for API lower than 31? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with using `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a `LocationRequest` on API Level 30 and below, because `LocationRequest` itself was added in API Level 31.

You should be able to [use `LocationRequestCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/location/LocationRequestCompat) as a backwards-compatible replacement, used [with `LocationManagerCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/location/LocationManagerCompat).

Answer (score 0):

Update location service library to the late version and use correct import, for me the latest version right now is

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
```

this version may have been changed when you will be seeing this answer, so make sure to update to the latest version.